# How many nodes need to install my custom plugin?

Tags: plugin, producers

If I create a custom plugin for EOS that provides an expanded RPC/API, is it sufficient to install that plugin on my local `nodeos` instance?  Or does it need to be installed on the block producers as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin will only be accessible to RPC clients which connect to nodes which run the plugin. A common case will be websites connecting to nodes running the plugins needed to support that website.

Comment: This seems no better than hosting your own custom-built server that wraps calls to the mainnet?