# Can a plugin be configured to only process irreversible blocks?

Tags: plugin, security, irreversible

We would like to implement a custom plugin within our own node, in order to listen to transactions from the main net, and then push relevant information to external services.

However, we are concerned with security. In particular, whether we can fully trust the transactions we are listening to, before we take some external action that we ourselves cannot reverse (e.g., bank deposit).

Is there a way to configure/program the plugin so that it only processes the blocks after they have become irreversible?

Also related:

- [How can one make an EOS plugin to just watch one smart contract actions and transactions](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/355/how-can-one-make-an-eos-plugin-to-just-watch-one-smart-contract-actions-and-tran/449)
- [Is there any method to know whether a transaction has been confirmed or not?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/395/is-there-any-method-to-know-whether-a-transaction-has-been-confirmed-or-not)
- [Can a smart contract communicate externally?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/418/can-a-smart-contract-communicate-externally/).

Answer (score 1):

there's a write-up on how exchanges should deal with deposits and withdrawals on the eos blockchain. It deals with irreversible blocks, might be useful:

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/exchange-deposit-withdraw